# ¿Por qué cuando se añade un icono en C# el archivo se detecta como virus?

Tags: c#

En mi proyecto de C# he creado una aplicación de consola, empleando la aplicación SharpDeveloper. Cuando compilo el proyecto a un ejecutable final, analizo el archivo y no detecta virus. El código del archivo .cs es

```c#
using System;

namespace Prueba {
    class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

El archivo AssemblyInfo.cs es

```c#
#region Using directives

using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

#endregion
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Prueba")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Prueba")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright 2021")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

El problema principal aparece cuando añado un icono al proyecto y lo exporto. Se detectan en un antivirus online dos amenazas:

MaxSecure: Trojan.Malware.300983.susgen
SecureAge APEX: Malicious

Esto no aparece si no añado el icono. He estado investigando y supongo que está referido al archivo AssemblyInfo.cs, no porque esté corrupto, sino porque posiblemente hay un problema con el copyright.

¿Alguna solución? ¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: Como curiosidad. que antivirus tienes? He notado que con el antivirus Kaspersky sucede esto regularmente.

Comment: @Jorgesys VirusTotal

Answer (score 0):

Se supone que debes definir mayor informaciòn sobre tu aplicaciòn por ejemplo, titulo, autor y una descripciòn o incluso cambiar el GUID.

pero sin haber cambiado lo anterior el principal problema es el nombre de tu aplicaciòn o clase principal, por ejemplo si tu proyecto o clase principal tiene como nombre:

- myApp
- myProgram
- Program
- myClass
- Application1
- myApplication
- Application
  etc...

esto es detectado por algunos antivirus como un virus real, te sugiero cambiar el nombre de tu clase o apliciòn o clase principal por algo màs real y evitaras este problema.

Comment: No funciona lo que has comentado. Cunando añado el icono detecta virus, si no añado icono, no detecta virus. El icono está limpio

Comment: Cambiaste el nombre de tu clase Program por que nombre?

Comment: Sí, pero de todas maneras, sigue dando amenazas. ¿Puede ser por el archivo AssemblyInfo.cs?